# PHP Autoincrement Array

Tags: php, arrays, indexing, key, key-value

I am having trouble with expanding my PHP array. Here is a sample of my code :

```
    <select name="PaymentCounts">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<?php
$arr = array ('Client' => "Alex", 'BillNumber' => "123", 'PaymentCounts' => "1", 'Amounts' =>
  array ('PaymentNumber' => 
    array( array('Amount1' => "100.00", 'AmountDate1' => "27.05.2015"))), 'ActiveClient => "1");
echo "<pre>";
    print_r($arr);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

This is how it looks like when PaymentsCount is 1. Can someone give me an approach, if Payments count is more than 1 my PHP array could auto expand and more specificly start copying this

```
   array('Amount1' => "100.00", 'AmountDate1' => "27.05.2015"),
   array('Amount2' => "100.00", 'AmountDate2' => "27.06.2015")
```

I think there must be combined if, for and push_array but I can't sort it out by myself. I would be really pleased if you also give me a suggestion how to make Amount$i and AmountDate$i index increse by one until it reaches the PaymentsCount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider using `for()` and `array_push()` function.

Schematic code could look like this:

```
    $paymentsArray = array();
$day = "27";
$month = "05";
$year ="2015";
            for($i=0; $i <= $PaymentCounts; $i++)
            {

        array_push($paymentsArray, array('Amount1' => "100.00", 'AmountDate1' => "$day.$month.$year"));
$month++;
            }
      $arr = array ('Client' => "Alex", 'BillNumber' => "123", 'PaymentCounts' => "1", 'Amounts' => $paymentsArray);
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I thought array_push adds only in the end of the array